# Add two columns in a dataframe to form a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Add two columns in a dataframe to form a list.

Add `a + b = ['a','b']`

df

```
        a       b
0      paul    ab
1      bruno   bc
```

Expected output

```
        a       b     c
0      paul    ab    ['paul','ab']
1      bruno   bc    ['bruno','bc']
```

I have tried this, result was in str.

```
'['+ df['a'] + ',' +  df['b'] + ']' gives '[paul,ab]'
```

Comment: Use `df['c'] = df.values.tolist()`

Comment: Thanks.How can i select custom columns instead of all ?

Comment: Use `df['c'] = df[['a','b']].values.tolist()`